# Robotframework-selenium2library installation on linux failed due to NameError with execfile

Tags: python, linux, selenium, installation, robotframework

I want to install the Selenium2Library.

When I run:

```
sudo easy_install robotframework-selenium2library
```

in my Ubuntu console I get the error:

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 242, in runner
_execfile(setup_script, ns)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 46, in _execfile
exec(code, globals, locals)
File "/tmp/easy_install-msislfw7/robotframework-selenium2library-1.7.4/setup.py", line 11, in <module>
NameError: name 'execfile' is not defined
```

Is this a version conflict between Python 2.7 and Python 3.4?
Could I provide more information?

**EDIT:**

When I run:

```
pip install robotframework-selenium2library
```

I get the error:

```
Collecting robotframework-selenium2library
  Using cached robotframework-selenium2library-1.7.4.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-build-hw1y4ldv/robotframework-selenium2library/setup.py", line 11, in <module>
        execfile(join(dirname(__file__), 'src', 'Selenium2Library', 'version.py'))
    NameError: name 'execfile' is not defined
```

Maybe I mixed up my Python 2.7 and Python 3.4 because execfile is used by Python 2.7 only. How to solve this problem?